# alternative to apple keychain tool

Tags: iphone, certificate

Which is the terminal command line equivalent for installing the development certificate (.cer file) without having access to Keychain Access utility?

I have an cloud rented MAC which doesn't offeer me access to the Keychain utility, but I'm allowed to use the terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is to use OpenSSL in order to convert the iOS developer certificate file into a PEM certificate file and then to generate a P12 file based on the PEM certificate and the certificate key earlier generated. [source](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/packaging-air-apps-ios.html)

```
openssl x509 -in developer_identity.cer -inform DER -out developer_identity.pem -outform PEM
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey mykey.key -in developer_identity.pem -out iOS_dev.p12
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to see if this works for you :

http://lists.apple.com/archives/apple-cdsa/2010/Mar/msg00021.html